# Swift JSON Decoding: Displaying Results

Tags: ios, json, swift, swiftui

I am trying to make a view that shows the stats of a bulb, I want to show if the device is on or off and what its brightness is. I already have an API that can return this information in JSON and also have a web GUI. But I want to make an app on my iPhone so I am very new to Swift so used this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_TrPJQWD8qs) to parse the JSON response from the API and print it to the console. I now don't know how to actually put the information I get into visible pieces of text. I will show you the JSON return I get and the code I have already done:

Parsed JSON

```
BulbInfo(error_code: 0, result: UITest.Result(device_on: true, brightness: 100))
```

*API return JSON*

```
{'error_code': 0, 
'result': {
'device_id': 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
 'fw_ver': '1.1.9 Build 20210122 Rel. 56165',
 'hw_ver': '1.0.0',
 'type': 'SMART.TAPOBULB',
 'model': 'L510 Series',
 'mac': 'xx-xx-xx-xx-xx-xx',
 'hw_id': 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
 'fw_id': 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
 'oem_id': 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
 'specs': 'EU',
 'lang': 'en_US',
 'device_on': True,
 'on_time': 3065,
 'overheated': False,
 'nickname': 'TWFpbiBMaWdodA==',
 'avatar': 'hang_lamp_1',
 'brightness': 100,
 'default_states': {
   'brightness': {
     'type': 'last_states',
     'value': 100
    }
   },
 'time_diff': 0,
 'region': 'Europe/London',
 'longitude': -xxxxx,
 'latitude': xxxxxx,
 'has_set_location_info': True,
 'ip': '192.168.x.xxx',
 'ssid': 'xxxxxxxxxxxx',
 'signal_level': 1,
 'rssi': -xx
 }
}
```

*ContentView.swift*

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
         
    func getDeviceInfo(){
        
        let urlString = "http://192.168.x.xxx:xxx/get_bulb_info"
        let url = URL(string:urlString)
        
        let session = URLSession.shared
        
        let dataTask = session.dataTask(with: url!){(data,response,error)in
            // Check for error
            if error == nil && data != nil {
                // Parse JSON
                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                do{
                    let bulbInfo = try decoder.decode(BulbInfo.self, from: data!)
                    
                    print(bulbInfo)
                    
                }
                catch{
                    print(error)
                }
                
            }
        }
        dataTask.resume()
        
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        
        Text("Main Light:").padding()
        Button(action:getDeviceInfo){
            Text("Get Device Info!")
        }
        
    }
}



struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
       
    }
}
```

*Bulb.swift*

```swift
//
//  Bulb.swift
//  UITest
//
//  Created by James Westhead on 18/12/2021.
//

import Foundation
struct BulbInfo: Codable{
    var error_code: Int
    var result: Result
}
struct Result: Codable{
    var device_on:Bool
    var brightness: Int
}
```

Comment: Make an `@State var bulbInfo: BulbInfo? = nil`(or something similar) and remove `let` from the `do` block

Comment: But then how do I display that in the view next to ```Text("Main Light: ")``` I tried adding it in a VStack like this ```Text(bulbInfo).font(.title)``` and it gives the error ```No exact matches in call to initializer```

Comment: You said your JSON parsing works so it should be something like `bulbInfo.result.device_on.description` or `bulbInfo.result.brightness.description`

Comment: ahhhhhh right okay thank you

Comment: I'm glad it helped, I added an answer with the info do you mind accepting it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add to `ContentView`

```
@State var bulbInfo: BulbInfo? = nil
```

Then remove the `let` from the `do catch` block

You can access the information by using something like

```
bulbInfo.result.device_on.description
```

or

```
bulbInfo.result.brightness.description
```

inside the `Text`